# Java unreachable catch block compiler error

Tags: java, scjp

Why in Java can we catch an `Exception` even if it is not thrown, but we can't catch it's subclass (except for "unchecked" `RuntimeException`s and it subclasses). Example code:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // do nothing
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // OK           
        }

        try {
            // do nothing
        } catch (IOException e) {
               // COMPILER ERROR: Unreachable catch block for IOException.
               //This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
        }       
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: that means there is nothing to catch (no error) i dont see the issue

Comment: You should read the Java Language Specification, or at least a good Java tutorial.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A `RuntimeException` could be thrown by *any* code. In other words, the compiler can't easily predict what kind of code can throw it. A `RuntimeException` can be caught by a `catch(Exception e)` block.

`IOException`, however, is a checked exception - only method calls which are declared to throw it can do so. The compiler can be (reasonably) confident that it can't possible occur unless there are method calls which are declared to throw it.

The Java compiler simply doesn't consider the "there's no code at all within the try block" situation - it always allows you to catch unchecked exceptions, as in all *reasonable* scenarios there will be code which *could* potentially throw an unchecked exception.

From [section 14.21](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.21) of the JLS:

> A catch block C is reachable iff both of the following are true:
>
> - Some expression or throw statement in the try block is reachable and can throw an exception whose type is assignable to the parameter of the catch clause C. (An expression is considered reachable iff the innermost statement containing it is reachable.)
> - There is no earlier catch block A in the try statement such that the type of C's parameter is the same as or a subclass of the type of A's parameter.

Arguably the compiler should realize that there are *no* expressions within the try block in your first case... it looks like this is still an unreachable catch clause, to me.

EDIT: As noted in comments, [section 14.20](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20) contains this:

> It is a compile-time error if a `catch` clause catches checked exception type *E1* but there exists no checked exception type *E2* such that all of the following hold:
>
> - *E2* <: *E1*
> - The `try` block corresponding to the `catch` clause can throw *E2*
> - No preceding `catch` block of the immediately enclosing try statement catches *E2* or a supertype of *E2*.
>
> unless *E1* is the class Exception.

So it looks like that's what you're *actually* running foul of, but the spec isn't as clear as it could be in terms of unreachable catch blocks in 14.21.

Comment: I think the solution is in [§ 14.20](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#79311), which explicitly says that `Exception` excempt from the "must be thrown" check: "[...] unless *`E1`* is the class `Exception`".

Comment: @Joachim: Well found. Will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

IO Exceptions can only be caught if the compiler predicts that there might be something in the code that throws IOException. So you are getting a warning that IO exception is never thrown from the try statement body (since there is nothing in the body of try).

Answer (score 3):

Because for checked exceptions the method that is throwing them, must explicitly state this fact by 'throws' keyword, thus if a block doesn't have the 'throws IOException' in your case, the compiler has the information it is *impossible* for an IOException to be thrown, so the whatever you do after catching, it would be unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't catch unthrown checked exceptions because they can't be thrown. You can catch `Exception` because an unchecked runtime exception IS an `Exception` and COULD potentially be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

`IOException` is a checked Exception that is only thrown by IO related code. Since your try block does nothing, nothing IO related will ever happen, IOExceptions will never be thrown, so there is no way the catch block will ever be executed and the compiler don't let you get around with it.
As you said, Exception may refer to unchecked Runtime Exceptions that may occur at any moment. That's the main difference between unchecked and checked exceptions, and that is why the compiler don't enforce the code to catch every possible runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Java assumes that any code line can throw a generic `Exception` or `Throwable`, ie. `OutOfMemoryException` which is an `Error` rather an `Exception`. Same applies for NPE.

`IOException` is a specific exception that can be thrown only by managed code, so if you don't have I/O calls in your catch block your compiler that there is no chance to catch it.

Just to compare to C# world, in C# such code would be compiled but would be a conceptual mistake since if you don't do anything you don't reach the catch block. A tool such as ReSharper can warn you about that.

Comment: The difference is that `IOException` (and all its sub-types) are **checked** exceptions, so the compiler can find out **exactly** which statements *could* throw them. `Exception` includes `RuntimeException` and therefore *could* happen in any statement (as they are unchecked and need not be declared).

Answer (score 0):

If we summarize from everyone's comment above, it can be concluded that fully checked exceptions like IOException and it's subclass are meant be to strictly checked by compiler and expected by relevant catch clause to throw. But in case of RuntimeException and Exception or Throwable (which both are partially checked exception, since they have RuntimeException as child/grandchild) compiler simply can't say at compile time and allow it to pass.

So..

```
try{
  // Empty - valid
} catch(Exception or Throwable or any Runtime Exception ){

}
```

but

```
try{
  // Empty - invalid and compile time error
} catch (Any fully checked Exception like IOException, FileNotFoundException, EOF/Interruped etc){

}
```