# Compile/ Catch an exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, catch-block

I am having a lot of trouble with this code. The code compiled and ran as it was suppose to before I tried to put in the code to catch an exception. Then I could no longer get it to compile. It is suppose to catch an exception and produce an error message if the user inputs a negative number.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; //Next group of lines import various Java classes
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SquareRoot extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        //Creates Window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setTitle("Find the Square Root");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel Numberlbl = new JLabel("Enter a number:");
        final JTextField NumberField = new JTextField(10);
        NumberField.setText("");

        JLabel Answerlbl = new JLabel("Square Root of your number is:");
        final JTextField AnswerField = new JTextField(10);
        AnswerField.setText("");

        JLabel ButtonLabel = new JLabel("Calculate Square Root");
        JButton button = new JButton("Find Square Root");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        panel.add(Numberlbl);
        panel.add(NumberField);
        panel.add(ButtonLabel);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(Answerlbl);
        panel.add(AnswerField);
        frame.add(panel);

        class CalculateListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                double NumberX = Double.parseDouble(NumberField.getText());
                try
                {
                    if(NumberX >=0);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Number can not be negative.");
                }
                double Answer = Math.sqrt(NumberX);
                AnswerField.setText(String.valueOf(Answer));

            }
        }

        ActionListener listener = new CalculateListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you try to compile?

Comment: SquareRoot.java:61: exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
    catch(IOException e)
    ^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java unreachable catch block compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899849/java-unreachable-catch-block-compiler-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need try-catch to check negative, below should be enough. But you may need try-catch when you do formatting.

```
double noX = 0;
try {
   noX = Double.parseDouble(NumberField.getText());
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("Not a valid number");
}
if(noX < 0) {
   System.out.println("Number can not be negative.");
}
```

Comment: True, but you should catch NumberFormatException in case someone tries passing "foo" to parseDouble().

Answer (score 0):

its better to use:

```
double NumberX = Double.parseDouble(NumberField.getText());
            if(NumberX <=0){
            System.out.println("Number can not be negative.");
            }
double Answer = Math.sqrt(NumberX);
AnswerField.setText(String.valueOf(Answer));
```

Comment: Yeah but for my assignment I have to catch an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans says "exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in corresponding if statement".

Basically if statements don't throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a custom exception..

```
              try
                {
                    if(NumberX >=0);
                    else
                      throw new Exception("Number Negative");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Number can not be negative."+e.getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is running good.

```
        package com.test;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SquareRoot extends JFrame {
  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creates Window
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(450, 300);
    frame.setTitle("Find the Square Root");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel Numberlbl = new JLabel("Enter a number:");
    final JTextField NumberField = new JTextField(10);
    NumberField.setText("");

    JLabel Answerlbl = new JLabel("Square Root of your number is:");
    final JTextField AnswerField = new JTextField(10);
    AnswerField.setText("");

    JLabel ButtonLabel = new JLabel("Calculate Square Root");
    JButton button = new JButton("Find Square Root");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
    panel.add(Numberlbl);
    panel.add(NumberField);
    panel.add(ButtonLabel);
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(Answerlbl);
    panel.add(AnswerField);
    frame.add(panel);

    class CalculateListener implements ActionListener {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        double NumberX;
        try {
          NumberX = Double.parseDouble(NumberField.getText());

          if (NumberX < 0) {
            AnswerField.setText("Please enter positive value.");
          }
          else if (NumberX >= 0) {
            double Answer = Math.sqrt(NumberX);
            AnswerField.setText(String.valueOf(Answer));
          }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          AnswerField.setText("Incorrect number entered.");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    ActionListener listener = new CalculateListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```