# Why can't I have a catch for a checked exception for a call that throws a generic?

Tags: java, generics, exception, try-catch

I am working on a small helper that is supposed to invoke arbitrary code (passed in as lambda). The helper should catch certain exceptions, and throw them inside some wrapper. My "own" exceptions should not be wrapped but just re-thrown.

I came up with this code:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Processable<T, X extends Throwable> {
    public T apply() throws X;
}

class MyCheckedException extends Exception { ... }
class MyCheckedExceptionWrapper extends MyCheckedException { ... }

public class MyExceptionLogger<T, X extends Throwable> {
    public T process(Processable<T, X> processable) throws MyCheckedException {
        try {
            return processable.apply();
        } catch (MyCheckedException thrown) { // this line isn't accepted
            throw thrown;
        } catch (Exception | LinkageError thrown) {
            throw new MyCheckedExceptionWrapper(thrown);
        } catch (Throwable thrown) {
           ... just log
          return null; 
        }
    }
}
```

The above gives a compile error:

> Unreachable catch block for MyCheckedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body MyExceptionLogger ...

In other words: although `apply()` is defined to throw some `X extends Throwable` I can't catch a specific checked exception when invoking that method.

I *know* that I can get to working code by catching **Throwable**, to then use `instanceof` checks - but I would like to understand **why** it is not possible to have a try/catch as outlined above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the spec mandates that caught checked exceptions need to be known to be potentially thrown by the try-block - and since `X` doesn't extend `MyCheckedException` the compiler doesn't know that exception would ever be thrown. Would changing `MyExceptionLogger` to `X extends MyCheckedException` be an option?

Comment: @Thomas Not really. I want to use this for very different invocation scenarios. There can be *all kinds* of checked exceptions. Some of them derive from "my" own base exceptions, others do not.

Comment: During compile time Java doesn't know about any specific type of Exception that an implementation of  `Processable` might throw, the only thing that is known, is that it is some subclass of `Throwable`. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899849/java-unreachable-catch-block-compiler-error) the respective parts of the Java spec are cited. But the spec is not too concrete regarding this issue. That is from reading the spec catching any checked exception should be fine, if a method declares `Throwable`.

Comment: [JLS 11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) states: "It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E1, unless E1 is Exception or a superclass of Exception." As I read that the compiler doesn't know that your body could throw `MyCheckedException` or even `Exception`.

Comment: @Thomas - you should have written down that in an answer ;-)

Comment: You're right, but I'll leave it a comment now as to not compete with blinkenlight's almost exact same answer ;)

Comment: What you could do (though not that pretty): use `instanceof` and casts to throw `MyCheckedException` out of the `catch( Exception | LingkageError )` block.

Comment: @Thomas All fine, I think we managed. And in case that answer gets even more upvotes, I will compensate further. And yes, the code I am currently looking at is doing that kind of catching/instanceof-ing.

Comment: Nah, you don't have to compensate ;) I'm here to help and learn, not to collect points.

Comment: @Thomas I think people should upvote much more ... so I try to lead by example ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is - based on the JSL - no good reason why you should not be able to catch your custom checked exception in your example.

If you read the cite from the JLS

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class `E1` and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of `E1`, unless `E1` is `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`.

A catch-clause should be allowed to catch **any** checked `Exception`, if a method in the corresponding try-block declares `Throwable`. In your example the try-block can *throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or **superclass** of `MyCheckedException`* namely `Throwable` and `MyCheckedException` is obviously not *`Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`*

This can easily be verified by removing the generics from the above example and see it compile without issues:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Processable<T> {
    public T apply() throws Throwable;
}


private <T> T process(Processable<T> aProcessable) {
    try {
        return aProcessable.apply();
    } catch (MyCheckedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

That is this problem somehow has to be related to the use of generics in combination with exceptions. Maybe this is related to type erasure, but with erased types your example works fine as well:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Processable {
    public Object apply() throws Throwable;
}


private Object process(Processable aProcessable) {
    try {
        return aProcessable.apply();
    } catch (MyCheckedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have to agree. In this case the solution is *really* about dropping the actually *pointless* generics for X. And for the record: I changed my code this morning and dropped that whole interface completely. Using util.Callable instead ... and that gets the job done too (and I actually do not need to have "throws Throwable" anywhere).

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is specified in [section 11.2.3 of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class `E1` and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of `E1`, unless `E1` is `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`.

`MyCheckedException` fits the description of `E1` class above, because it is not declared in the generic declaration of `processable.apply()`, and it is not `Exception` or one of its superclasses. The compiler knows only that the method can throw a `Throwable`, so `MyCheckedException` is not declared.

Comment: Actually by declaring `Throwable` the try-block could throw a sub-class of `MyCheckedException`. That is according to the spec it should be fine to catch any checked exception, if `Throwable` is declared in the try-block. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dpr `Throwable` is not a checked exception.

Comment: @dpr To expand on blinkenlight's comment, the spec says "...a _checked exception_ class that is a subclass or superclass of E1", i.e. if `Exception` were used instead of `Throwable` it should work according to that definition - but not with `Throwable` itself.

Comment: Yes, I got this. But by `Exception` is subclass of `Throwable`. That is by declaring `Throwable` the try-block can throw any type of exception including `MyCheckedException`

Comment: @Thomas I tried and changed my code to use `<X extends Exception>` - but the error messages sticks. When I change it to `<X extends MyException>` - then I can add that catch. But as written above - I can't do that because my lambdas will be throwing other stuff as well.

Comment: [11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1) appears to state that `Throwable` is a checked exception. *"The checked exception classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are Throwable and all its subclasses other than RuntimeException and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses."*

Comment: Yes, `Throwable` is a checked exception. If you write `throw new Throwable("Catch me");` the compiler will require you to handle `Throwable`.