# Can c code raise java exceptions?

Tags: java, c, exception, native

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to throw exceptions in JNI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230689/best-way-to-throw-exceptions-in-jni-code)

I see that the [System#arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) could throw `ArrayStoreException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException` etc.
But I also saw that [System#arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) is a using a `native` method, which means `C` code, right?
So how is it possible that `C` code could throw any of these `java` exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

There are no problems in throwing java exception from native code. You can do this easily with code like this one:

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/ArrayStoreException");
env->ThrowNew(cls, message);
```

Comment: Don't forget to clean up and return afterwards... It is a common newbe mistake to assume that an ThrowNew() will immediately return, just like a throw would normally do.

Comment: The `<jni.h>` interface also provides a `jint (*Throw)(JNIEnv*, jthrowable);` alternative API that is useful when you need to create your own/specific throwable object via `NewObject`.