# attempts to catch native jni crash/SIGSEGV in java are failing

Tags: java, android, c, crash, java-native-interface

I'm trying to 'catch' a crash (SIGSEGV) in java.

This crash happens in the C code and I would like to report that failure correctly in java.

So that the whole app doesn't crash when the native code crashes I managed to move the call to the native code to another process inside a 'Service' (by use of `android:process=":ffmpeg"` in AndroidManifest.xml). This works fine.

Right now I tried:

- to add a signer handler in the C code and throw a java exception from there. `throwFfmpegHelperException(a, "throwFfmpegHelperException message");`
- to add a signer handler in the C code and call a java function from there.  `(*a)->CallStaticVoidMethod(a, obj, nativeCrashed);`
- to use the 'thread' approach by setting the uncaught exception handler of a java thread with: `t.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

However none of theses actually runs the code I put in java (ie. throws the java Exception I would like to see triggered).

**Any idea what could be wrong here? Any alternative?**
For now, my workaround is to wait for some time the reply from the service and if timeout is reached, consider it means that the service crashed.

##### Service (java)

contains the call to the 'java class that will call native function' & thread with its `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

```java
public class FfmpegBoundService extends Service {
    /**
     * Command to the service to display a message
     */
    static final int MSG_SAY_HELLO = 1;

    /**
     * Handler of incoming messages from clients.
     */
    static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        Bitmap tb;
        Messenger clientMessenger;

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_SAY_HELLO:
                    clientMessenger = msg.replyTo;
                    Runnable doSwscale = () -> {
                        try {
                            tb = Smooth.rescale_with_crash((Bitmap) msg.obj, msg.arg1, msg.arg2, Smooth.AlgoParametrized1.LANCZOS, 3.0);  // 3 is default width in ffmpeg.
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    };

                    Thread t = new Thread(doSwscale);

                    // Set UncaughtExceptionHandler to catch crash
                    t.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.
                            UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                            try {
                                throw new FfmpegHelperException("ffmpeg Crash");
                            } catch (Exception e2) {
                                e2.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    t.start();

                    // Wait until thread is finished.
                    try {
                        t.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Reply to client and send the thumbnail
                    Message reply = Message.obtain(null, 10, tb);
                    try {
                        clientMessenger.send(reply);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Target we publish for clients to send messages to IncomingHandler.
     */
    Messenger mMessenger;

    /**
     * When binding to the service, we return an interface to our messenger
     * for sending messages to the service.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    }
}
```

##### java (call to native function)

```java
public class Smooth implements Serializable {
    public static Bitmap rescale_with_crash(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
                                 AlgoParametrized1 algo, double p0) throws Exception {
        Bitmap aa = null;
        int a = native_rescale_with_crash(src, Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, src.getConfig()),
                algo.flag, p0, 0.0);
        return aa;
    }

    static void nativeCrashed() throws Exception {
        //new RuntimeException("crashed here (native trace should follow after the Java trace)").printStackTrace();
        //Log.e("eta", "crashed here (native trace should follow after the Java trace)");
        throw new FfmpegHelperException("native crashed here ");
    }

    private static native Bitmap native_rescale(Bitmap src, Bitmap dst, int algo, double p0, double p1);
    private static native int native_rescale_with_crash(Bitmap src, Bitmap dst, int algo, double p0, double p1);
}
```

##### C code

```c
jint throwFfmpegHelperException( JNIEnv *env, char *message );

JNIEnv *a;
static jclass obj;
static jmethodID nativeCrashed;

void Segfault_Handler(int signo)
{
    //(*a)->CallStaticVoidMethod(a, obj, nativeCrashed);
    throwFfmpegHelperException(a, "throwFfmpegHelperException message");
    signal(signo, SIG_DFL);
    raise(signo);
}

static int JNICALL native_rescale_impl_with_crash(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                           jobject srcBitmap, jobject dstBitmap, jint sws_algo, jdouble p0, jdouble p1) {

    signal(SIGSEGV,Segfault_Handler);
    a = env;
    obj = clazz;
    raise(SIGSEGV);
    return 200;
}

static const char *g_rescaler_java_class = "com/schokoladenbrown/Smooth";
static const JNINativeMethod g_native_methods[] = {
    {"native_rescale",
     "(Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;IDD)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;",
     native_rescale_impl},
    {"native_rescale_with_crash",
            "(Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;IDD)I",
            native_rescale_impl_with_crash},
};

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved) {
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    jclass cls;

    (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, &env, NULL);
    cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, g_rescaler_java_class);
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls, g_native_methods, sizeof g_native_methods / sizeof g_native_methods[0]);
    nativeCrashed = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls,  "nativeCrashed", "()V");

}

jint throwNoClassDefError_( JNIEnv *env, char *message )
{
    jclass exClass;
    char *className = "java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError";

    exClass = (*env)->FindClass( env, className);
    if (exClass == NULL) {
        return throwNoClassDefError_( env, className );
    }

    return (*env)->ThrowNew( env, exClass, message );
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230689/best-way-to-throw-exceptions-in-jni-code

jint throwFfmpegHelperException( JNIEnv *env, char *message )
{
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env) == JNI_TRUE) {
        return 99;
    }

    jclass exClass;
    char *className = "com/exifthumbnailadder/app/exception/FfmpegHelperException" ;

    exClass = (*env)->FindClass( env, className );
    if ( exClass == NULL ) {
        return throwNoClassDefError_( env, className );
    }

    return (*env)->ThrowNew( env, exClass, message );
}
```

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083154/how-can-i-catch-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-and-get-a-stack-trace-under-jni-on

Comment: Already tried, without more success :/